# How to make variable values available for use in another class?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I've tried a number of things with this, including the solutions from similar questions on here, but still no joy.

I am using a scanner to get values for the two variables `patientName` and `patientAddress` and then I want those values to be transferred to another class, but when I try it the values come in as `null`. Here is the code.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Patients {

    String patientName;
    String patientAddress;

    public void patientDetails() {
        Scanner patientScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input a patients name");
        patientName = patientScanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please input a patients address");
        String patientAddress = patientScanner.nextLine();
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println(patientName);
        System.out.println(patientAddress);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.patientName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.patientAddress;
   }
}
```

Comment: How do you make a call to get values?

Comment: Where's the second class? Where do you get the error from?

Comment: Except of `patientAddress = patientScanner.nextLine()`, I'm pretty sure your problem is not in `Patients` class: http://ideone.com/EjmBjf

Answer (score 2):

Variable scope I reckon.

Change this:

```
String patientAddress = patientScanner.nextLine();
```

to this

```
patientAddress = patientScanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: That's not it I'm afraid, they're still coming in as null values.